# How to unlock color scheme attributes?

Tags: phpstorm, phpstorm-2018.1

If I select a start tag, then the according end tag is highlighted. However, the highlight color almost matches my background color, so it is barely visible.

[image]

Is there a way to make this more obvious?

I searched in "File -> Settings -> Editor -> Color Scheme -> HTML -> Tag Tree Level (1)"

But I can only set the background color attribute, and the other ones are grayed out for unknown reasons.

[image]

Is there a way to unlock these attributes and make it blink or something?

Comment: *"Is there a way to unlock these attributes and make it blink or something?"* No. You can configure only available styles. Maybe you should try more contrast colors? I do not see any bright red on your first screenshot.

Comment: @LazyOne "*I do not see any bright red on your first screenshot*" exactly, thats the problem ;)

Comment: OK .. please clarify what exactly you want to change (what to achieve). If you want to highlight tag structure like this https://postimg.cc/image/kfxtpui1p/ ... then you just need to make those colors less transparent -- Change `Opacity` to a higher number (`0.9` or whatnot) from default `0.1` (barely visible) at `Settings/Preferences | Editor | General | Appearance --> Enable HTML/XML tag tree highlighting`

Comment: Basically I just want to make it obvious where the opening/closing tag of the selected tag are.

Comment: In such case that `Opacity` option should do the job (result is shown on my screenshot). If you want that current tag only ... you may disable colors for other levels ... or limit number of levels (next to Opacity) .. or maybe even "Matched brace" style for "Settings/Preferences | Editor | Color Scheme | General" (not exactly  .. but still related)